# “Jumping” over a person’s position who is of higher rank

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english, british-english

What term would I use to describe the act of “jumping” over a person’s position who has held office longer or in a higher position than oneself.

*e.g: Being promoted to become the boss that my current boss reports to.*

Basically I get the opportunity to move up the rank that my own boss (who has held his post longer than myself) would have been up for, hence skipping him as he now reports to me not the other way around.

I hope that made sense.

Comment: I added the request tag, please edit the other two tags. If your question is regarding just AmE or just BrE keep that tag. Otherwise you can delete both tags.

Comment: Not a dead-on match, but an important variant of this phenomenon is *percussive sublimation*, a term introduced in [*The Peter Principle*](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/Peter-principle).  (Oddly, the Wikipedia article on *The Peter Principle* omits this valuable addition to the English lexicon.)

Comment: *I've **surpassed** my boss and now he/she reports to me.*

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It sounds as though such a person is about to **leapfrog** over his superior and land a corporate position in which his erstwhile superior/boss has now become his subordinate or underling.

**leapfrog:** to go straight from a job or position that was lower in status than someone's to one that is higher than theirs (Macmillan Dictionary).

Answer (score 16):

I would describe this as "**leap-frogging**."

"Leap-frog" is a childhood game.

> 1. A boys' game in which one player places his hands upon the bent back or shoulders of another and leaps or vaults over him. Also, a jump or leap of this description. ([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106706?rskey=eHFBHX&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid))

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leapfrog) has a better example of this metaphorical usage:

> Skipping his last two years of high school, he leapfrogged his classmates and went to college.

Comment: Great minds think alike! Did you leapfrog over me or did I leapfrog over you? croak-croak-croak!

Comment: not quite sure why MW thinks it's gender specific?

Comment: While I would agree, it technically isn't a gender specific game, I do recall as a child this game was played predominantly by boys. (Though I must admit to possibly being a little biased myself due to my own gender.)

Comment: @jk Did you ever try playing leapfrog in a skirt? You could argue that girls don't wear skirts these days, but I'm not sure children of the 21st century still play leap-frog either.

Comment: @jk. That's actually OED, but your point stands.

Comment: @PeterPoint Well, guess it depends on who ends up with more votes :P

Answer (score 4):

I would simply say "I was **promoted above** my boss."

You can say the same thing for any promotion, really.  "I was promoted above my co-workers" for a single step up.  The reference to "my boss" implies that you've moved up two steps rather than just one, and that your former boss is now your subordinate.

Comment: @JoeBlow I think you have leapfrogged over me and sounded off unfairly against poor old Steve-O. Croak & thrice croak.

Comment: @JoeBlow Quite so, Joe Blow. Someone is blowing kisses at me in cyberspace. I've just turned into a Prince! Pete Prince, formerly known as: